# Align long equation in paragraph

Tags: math-mode, paragraphs

I have latex text that has a long equation in it. I want the equation to be aligned with the text and not extend over its right border.

`In graph theory, a Graph $G = (V,E)$ is defined over a set of vertices $V=V(G)$ and a set of edges $E=E(G)$. A  path is a sequence ${x_1,x_2,...,x_n}$ such that $(x_1,x_2), (x_2,x_3), ...,  (x_(n-1),x_n) \subseteq   E(G)$ and the $x_i$ are distinct. A cycle is a subset of the $E(G)$ that forms a path such that the first node of the path corresponds to the last.`

Compiling the above, I get the following output:

[image: overleaf output]

How can I force the part of `$(x_1,x_2), (x_2,x_3), ...,  (x_(n-1),x_n) \subseteq E(G)$` to be aligned with the text in my paragraph?

Comment: use `\linebreak` after `\ldots,`  (and use `\ldots` not `...`)

Comment: You have an error as well, `(x_(n-1),x_n)` should be `(x_{(n-1)},x_n)`. As an alternative to Davis suggestion I'd use `,\allowbreak `, aka add `\allowbreak` after the commas where a line break is allowed. Then LaTeX can choose an appropriate one. In general LaTeX will not by it self linebreak after a comma in math mode.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, but the main issue is remained since the break is not guaranteed to be in the same line width as the lines above and below

Comment: You might consider placing the long math segment in display mode, i.e., use `\[...\]` instead of `$...$`.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be doing `\usepackage{palatino}` and set a textwidth of 13cm. Indeed, I can reproduce the output with

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
  textwidth=13cm
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
In graph theory, a Graph $G = (V,E)$ is defined over a set of 
vertices $V=V(G)$ and a set of edges $E=E(G)$. A  path is a 
sequence ${x_1,x_2,...,x_n}$ such that 
$(x_1,x_2), (x_2,x_3), ...,  (x_(n-1),x_n) \subseteq   E(G)$ 
and the $x_i$ are distinct. A cycle is a subset of the $E(G)$ 
that forms a path such that the first node of the path 
corresponds to the last. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

There are a few things before treating the overfull line issue.

1. Do `\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}` or `\usepackage{mathpazo}` to get a matching math font.
2. Fix the wrong subscript: it should be `x_{n-1}` (with braces) rather than `x_(n-1)`
3. Use `\dots` instead of `...`, along with `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

OK, the problem worsens…

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
  textwidth=13cm
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
In graph theory, a Graph $G = (V,E)$ is defined over a set of 
vertices $V=V(G)$ and a set of edges $E=E(G)$. A  path is a 
sequence ${x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n}$ such that 
$(x_1,x_2), (x_2,x_3), \dots,  (x_{n-1},x_n) \subseteq   E(G)$ 
and the $x_i$ are distinct. A cycle is a subset of the $E(G)$ 
that forms a path such that the first node of the path 
corresponds to the last. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

How to remedy? The first thing to try is to reword the paragraph. For instance, we see that the `\subseteq` symbol should rather be `\in` and that there is no specification that the edges should be ordered pairs of vertices.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
  textwidth=13cm
}

\linespread{1.04}% Palatino wants more room between lines

\begin{document}

\noindent
In graph theory, a \emph{graph} $G = (V,E)$ is defined over a set of 
vertices $V=V(G)$ and a set of edges $E=E(G)$, which is a subset of $V\times V$. 
A \emph{path} is a sequence of vertices ${x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n}$ such that 
$(x_1,x_2), (x_2,x_3), \dots,  (x_{n-1},x_n) \in E(G)$ 
and the $x_i$ are distinct, with the possible exception of $x_1$ and~$x_n$. 
If $x_1=x_n$, the path is called a \emph{cycle}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

This doesn't always work, but in tough cases you may try and add `\linebreak` after a comma in those long sequences.

*Mathematical note*: I don't think you want that the *vertices* in a path are distinct, but rather the *edges*. In this case the text might read

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
  textwidth=13cm
}

\linespread{1.04}% Palatino wants more room between lines

\begin{document}

\noindent
In graph theory, a \emph{graph} $G = (V,E)$ is defined over a set of 
vertices $V=V(G)$ and a set of edges $E=E(G)$, which is a subset of $V\times V$. 
A \emph{path} is a sequence of vertices ${x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n}$ such that 
$(x_1,x_2), (x_2,x_3), \dots,  (x_{n-1},x_n) \in E(G)$ 
and the edges are distinct. If $x_1=x_n$, the path is called a \emph{cycle}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In some introductory graph theory texts (e.g., Bollobás or Chartrand/Zhang) a path must have distinct vertices. In this case, a cycle is not a path because of the repeated end vertices.